# Include javascript file in freemarker template using spark

Tags: javascript, jetty, freemarker, spark-java

I've tried to include javascript file in ftl (Freemarker Template)

[image: js script tag]

but I keep getting this message

[image: console error]

I'm using Spark framework which has Jetty server. This happens every time I try to include any file, even just an image. With css I've used `<#include "style.css">` but it's workaround.

Is there any way to include scripts?

Comment: Did you mean `spark-java` instead of `apache-spark`? Show your Java code. Do you use [`staticFileLocation`](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#static-files)?

Comment: Yes, didn't notice. No, I don't use `staticFileLocation`, should I?

Comment: Yes. Use it like the documentation says.

Comment: Well, I've added `staticFileLocation` and it works, thanks a lot!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [staticFileLocation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#static-files) to tell where static files like *.js and *.css are placed, so spark will serve them directly.

Secondly, don't include css like that:

```
<#include "css/style.css">
```

because it will end up with css rules inside `<head>` tag, which will not work.